# add a shape legend to ggplot R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a ggplot and I want to add a legend to it, but it reflects only color and not  the shape. I used scale_shape_manual, but it still does not work. Here is what I have

```
plot <- ggplot(data.frame(labels, yes.percent.avgs.gc, yes.percent.avgs.dp, yes.percent.avgs.gm)) +
  geom_point(aes(x=labels, y=yes.percent.avgs.gc, colour="GC"), shape=16, size=5) + # Plot individual points
  geom_point(aes(x=labels, y=yes.percent.avgs.dp, colour="DP"), shape=17, size=5) + # Plot individual points
  geom_point(aes(x=labels, y=yes.percent.avgs.gm, colour="GM"), shape=18, size=5) + # Plot individual points
  geom_smooth(data=data.frame(labels, pred.avgs), aes(x=labels, y=pred.avgs, colour="Prediction Scores"), fill=NA, method=lm, size=1) +
  xlab("Bin range") +
  ylab("Argument Score") +
  theme(legend.position = c(0.8, 0.2))+
  scale_shape_manual(name = "Legend",
                     labels = c("GC", "DP", "GM"),
                     values = c(16, 17, 18))

plot # show the plot
```

How can I get the legend to show both color and shape.

Comment: If you want automatic legend for shape, put `shape=` inside `aes()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, the problem is that you are putting three `geom_point` layers on top of each other. This confuses `ggplot` which uses all shapes at once in legend.

The solution is to tidy your data before plotting it. Since you haven't provided [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), I had to make it up.

```
library("ggplot2")
library("tidyr")
set.seed(123)
labels <- sample(c("L1","L2", "L3", "L4"), 12, replace = TRUE)
yes.percent.avgs.gc <- sample(1:100, 12)
yes.percent.avgs.dp <- sample(1:100, 12)
yes.percent.avgs.gm <- sample(1:100, 12)

tidy.df <- gather(data.frame(labels, 
                             yes.percent.avgs.gc, 
                             yes.percent.avgs.dp, 
                             yes.percent.avgs.gm),
                  group, value,
                  yes.percent.avgs.gc, yes.percent.avgs.dp, yes.percent.avgs.gm)

plot <- ggplot(tidy.df) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=labels, y=value, colour=group, shape=group), size=5) + 
  xlab("Bin range") +
  ylab("Argument Score") + 
  scale_shape_manual(name = "Legend",
                     labels = c("GC", "DP", "GM"),
                     values = c(16, 17, 18)) + 
  scale_colour_manual(name="Legend",
                      labels=c("GC", "DP", "GM"),
                      values=c("Red", "Green", "Blue"))
print(plot)
```

[image: ggplot]

I have dropped `geom_smooth` call, because I could not see any difference between plots with and without it.

Comment: This is just what I was looking for!. Thanks for the link to tidyr library.